# Unable to make post calls after disabling JsonIgnore Annotation in SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I am facing an issue I have an shared EntityClass like this. it is used to place updated and created time in the entities.

```
@Getter @Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractEntity {

    @CreationTimestamp
    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name = "created_on", updatable = false)
    protected Instant createdOn;

    @UpdateTimestamp
    //@JsonIgnore
    @Column(name = "updated_on")
    protected Instant updatedOn;
}
```

Now we need to show the updatedOn time as part of our response so we removed the @JsonIgnore Annotation and then the get calls are working fine. But the post calls stopped working. The following error is being displayed:

InvalidDefinitionException: Java 8 date/time type `java.time.Instant` not supported by default: add Module "com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310" to enable handling (through reference chain: com.abc.adconfigservice.entity.config.AdConfigEntity["updatedOn"])]

As needed I added following dependency in the pom.xml but still the same error is coming.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-module-parameter-names</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Following is the configuration class

```
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CorsConfiguration {
    private final ApplicationProperties applicationProperties;

    @Bean("CorsConfigurer")
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**")
                        .allowedOrigins(applicationProperties.getCorsAllowOrigins())
                        .allowedHeaders("*")
                        .allowedMethods("GET", "PUT", "POST", "PATCH", "DELETE")
                        .allowCredentials(false);
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
        return objectMapper;
    }
}
```

I have also added and registered JavaTimeModule with Object Mapper but couldn't succeed.

The created and updated time are added by DB directly. here is the common part used in all tables.

```
    `created_on`       datetime                               Default now(),
    `updated_on`       datetime                               Default now() on update now()
```

Please suggest what else am missing.

Java version: 11.0.10
Spring Details: Spring Boot v2.5.12, Spring v5.3.18

Comment: Do you configure the ObjectMapper yourself? If yes, you need to register that new module: `new ObjectMapper().registerModule(new JavaTimeModule())`.

Comment: Yes, I have tried that as well. Added in description.

Answer (score 0):

You need to register `JavaTimeModule`. Add this bean in your configuration class:

```
@Bean 
ObjectMapper objectMapper() { 
  ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper(); 
   objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule()); 
  return objectMapper;
 }
```

Comment: I have tried this as well. but got the same error. Added this in the description itself now. What else we can do?

Comment: Can you post how your configuration looks like and how do you send request?

Comment: I am sending request with help of postman. The created and updated columns are being added by the db itself. It is maintained with help of db help.